# Storing values from knockout radio button values in observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new at knockout and I've been searching for an answer to the following question without finding an answer:
I several lists of radiobuttons and I want to store the selected value of the selected radiobutton in each of the radio button lists in an array (first index in the array should contain the selected value from the first radio button list and so on). Can this be done in any way?

See my code below to see what I'm trying to do. Basically I want to store the selected radio button values in the observableArray selectedProducts.

```js
function Product(id, name, room) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.room = room;
}

var listOfProds = [
  new Product(1, 'Prod1', 1),
  new Product(2, 'Prod2', 1),
  new Product(3, 'Prod3', 1),
  new Product(1, 'Prod1', 2),
  new Product(2, 'Prod2', 2),
  new Product(3, 'Prod3', 2)
];

var viewModel = {
  products: ko.observableArray(listOfProds),
  selectedProducts: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: products">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {name: 'room'+room}, checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedProducts" />[
    <span data-bind="text: room"></span>]
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
```

Comment: more clarity on what exactly you looking for is appreciated . are you looking for something like this for radio buttons http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/Q4LSQ/22/

Comment: in this case i want the $data to end up in the selectedProducts array with room 1 on index 1 in the array, room 2 on index 2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `selectedProducts` needs to be an array of observables, rather than an observable array, so that the actual contents are monitored, rather than it's length:

```
this.selectedProducts=[ko.observable(),ko.observable(),ko.observable() ];
```

Then you can bind the radioboxes as follows:

```
 <input type="radio" data-bind="
   attr: {name: 'room'+room}, 
   checkedValue: $data,
   checked: $root.selectedProducts[$data.room-1]"/>
```

There are probably more flexible ways to map the rooms to the length of selectedProducts (and you may want an observableArray of observables if the number of rooms is not fixed), and the `$data.room-1` snippet mightn't generalise if your rooms aren't consecutive integers, but this should give you some direction.

The full code is at http://jsfiddle.net/yq6jx8v7/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me mate. Your suggestion is general enough to suit my purpose at least for the moment :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try to bind onclick event and make selectedProducts manually.

Html:

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {name: 'room'+room}, click: $root.addSelectedElement" />
```

Click binding:

```
self.addSelectedElement = function(data) {
    var productInRoomArr = self.selectedProducts().filter(function(product) {
        return product.room == data.room;
    });
    if (productInRoomArr.length > 0) {
        var productInRoom = productInRoomArr[0];
        if (productInRoom.id == data.id)
            return true;
        var index = self.selectedProducts.indexOf(productInRoom);
        if (index > -1) {
            self.selectedProducts.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    self.selectedProducts.push(data);
    return true;}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc77zegs/)